# Does "much" imply "a great thing" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> She threw a sharp, sideways glance at Dumbledore here, as though
>   hoping he was going to tell her something, but he didn't, so she went
>   on. "A fine thing it would be if, on the very day You-Know-Who seems
>   to have disappeared at last, the Muggles found out about us all. I
>   suppose he really has gone, Dumbledore?"  "It certainly seems so,"
>   said Dumbledore. "We have **much** to be thankful for. Would you care
>   for a lemon drop?" (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is *much* implying ‘*a great thing*’ and indicating the previous ‘*he really has gone*’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In this case the word **much** simply means **a lot of things** or **a lot of events**

The following sentences are semantically equivalent:

> "It certainly seems so," said Dumbledore. "We have **much** to be thankful for. Would you care for a lemon drop?"
>
> "It certainly seems so," said Dumbledore. "We have **a lot of things** to be thankful for. Would you care for a lemon drop?"
>
> "It certainly seems so," said Dumbledore. "We [should] be thankful for **the many [fortunate] [events/things/people] [in our lives]**. Would you care for a lemon drop?"

In both cases, Dumbledore is saying that there are many things (in life) that we should be grateful for, and hence that Harry Potter should in this case not dwell on the unfortunate things in life, since there are many fortunate events that he is overlooking.